# How to resolve WebappClassLoaderBase

Tags: java, mongodb, apache

**When I am starting the server, it is getting started but I am getting errors. Due to this not able to do APIs call. These are the errors.**

```
Jul 18, 2018 11:05:36 PM com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable run
WARNING: Exception in monitor thread during notification of server state change
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ChangeEvent
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.sendStateChangedEvent(ServerMonitor.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(ServerMonitor.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.ChangeEvent]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1362)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1219)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.ChangeEvent]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1360)
    ... 5 more

Jul 18, 2018 11:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1219)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(ServerMonitor.java:177)
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(ServerMonitor.java:158)
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(ServerMonitor.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "cluster-2-34.214.191.171:27017" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(ServerMonitor.java:177)
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(ServerMonitor.java:158)
    at com.mongodb.ServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(ServerMonitor.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with this class

`@Component
 public class APIsAuthentications implements Filter`

which is used for `APIs Authentications`. In this class there is a method called:

`@Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse response, 
 FilterChain chain)throws IOException, ServletException`

this is validating `APIs` and expecting `token/authentication` in `requests header`.
Here `doFilter` method validating APIs for base URLs also and giving response `401`. There is no issues with tomcat.

Finally, I put the one condition in `doFilter` method if it's `base URLs/Open URLs` then there will no validations for these APIs.

My Base URL for local machines: `http://localhost:8080/projects/`

Problem solved !!! :)

Comment: what do you mean by base URL? Can you please confirm?

Comment: Base URLs can be : `/` or,  `http://localhost:8080/` or, `https://domainName.com/`. It is something that tomcat take default while starting the backend server.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your project is not packaged properly.
Please check your webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib folder (under your tomcat directory) to see if your dependencies are copied over or not.